# Override values in ODE integration with scipy.integrate.odeint

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, odeint

I am conducting numerical integration of a system of ODEs using scipy.integrate.odeint. **In the abstract, I want to be able to give the solver an arbitrary condition to apply to its output values.** For instance: if the value of a term (e.g. `X[0]`) is less than 1, override the value to 0, rather than using the value computed by numerical integration. Then carry on integration.

Here is an example of how I approach the integration.

```
# Toy ODE system to be integrated
def dXdt(X, t, args):
    return [args[0]*X[0], t*args[1]*X[1]]

# Setup initial conditions and integrate the system.
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
t = np.linspace(0, 100, 100) # timepoints to integrate
x0 = [100, 100] # initial conditions
args = [-.01, -.02]
X = odeint(dXdt, x0, t, args=(args,))
```

A workaround to achieve approximately the behavior I want would be to modify `dXdt` as follows:

```
def dXdt(X, t, args):
    if X[0] > 1: # make dX[0]/dt extremely negative to force X[0] toward 0
        return [-1e200, t*args[1]*X[1]] 
    return [args[0]*X[0], t*args[1]*X[1]]
```

This is obviously not generalizable to other conditions that might be desirable, and also does not solve the problem precisely (a precise solution would require knowledge of the solver's step size in `dXdt`.

Comment: Why something like 

`X[X <1] = 0` after odeint call
doesn't work for you? Basically, applying a condition to output of odeint as you state in the beginning.

Comment: @DmitryPetrov in this toy example it would, but if different elements of X depend on one another, it would not work, since those terms need the correct value at the time of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You have to consider `odeint` as black box where you have no access to the internal state and the steps taken during the integration.
In other contexts (languages, libraries) you have an event-action mechanism, where you can define the event of crossing some value downwards and take the action to modify the state.

In `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` you have one-half of that implemented, the event mechanism. You would have to define the event as terminal, extract the last state at the event, modify it and restart the integration with the modified state. In the end you can then concatenate the solution segments.